# How to clear the console screen when introducing input in Java?

Tags: java, console

Is there a way to clear the console when the Java program detects the user it's introducing some data?

I'm executing a program that does the following:

```
User: //enter username
//show data of the username
```

I want to make it so the user can search for as many users he want until he ends the execution.
To make it clear and nice, after each username search, I want to clear the screen when the program detects the user is typing something (filling the buffer).

Is there any way to do this?

This is the code I'm using to clear the console (this does not detect when the user is typing):

```
public static void clearScreen() {
    System.out.print("\033[H\033[2J");
    System.out.flush();
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What are you using to read the data? Why can't you read characters and wait on a \n'?

Comment: I'm using a simple Scanner to read the data. I could wait for a '\n' to clear it, yes, but I was wondering if there was a possibility on doing it automatically when the buffer is filling up.

Comment: It depends on if you are using a specific console or the command line(in this case it is not possible). Your only alternative is to iterate across the characters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use `System.in` without pressing the ENTER key at the end. Its the only way. `System.in` is not aware of the user input until enter is pressed. So if you are using a normal command line to do this, this won't work and you have to stick different raw command lines like [jline](https://github.com/jline/jline3)

For example :

```
Terminal terminal = TerminalBuilder.builder().system(true).jna(true).build();
terminal.enterRawMode(); //this enters into a raw mode and get's input on reader
reader = terminal.reader();
//finally
reader.close();
```

You can check it out. Although it highly doesn't make sense to bring in more dependencies unless you really want to and could just stick to a simple `while loop`

If you are using maven here's the dependency you can use.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jline</groupId>
    <artifactId>jline</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

By default, a terminal can only output text line by line.

Moving the cursor around, changing colors or clearing the screen requires special escape sequences that are interpreted by the terminal emulator in which you run your application.

C programs in Linux would usually do this via the ncurses library.

Java programs can do something similar with Lanterna (https://github.com/mabe02/lanterna) but within a GUI window. See also this article, which names other alternatives and shows how to use Lanterna: http://rememberjava.com/cli/2017/01/22/ncurses_terminal_libs.html